# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli error

Tags: mysqli

I have a problem with my scripts I need to change minimal of 30 scripts to the "new" mysqli but its terrible I know some basics but now I'm complete lost...

The connection to the database is ok, but now I have this error with this kind of rule in the script.... can someone help me out so I can learn from it ?

```
$sql_email_check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT email 
FROM  users  WHERE email='$email' AND status='Alive'");  


$sql_username_check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], 
"SELECT username FROM users  WHERE username='$reg_username'");
```

Update 1:

I cleared the error from the first rule of the script, i saw something on google similair. 
This was my script: 
$sql_email_check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND status='Alive'");

And now this:

$sql_email_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND status='Alive'");

i replaced: $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], with $con,  $con i have already dentifyed in a other filte with the connection with db and included in this file Is this right and will it work ? the error's are disapearing but if it will work ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Hi Thanks for your message! But i still dont get it.....   In the past i learned the basis php by editing scripts and i always had a good script with the correct coding. could you help me out with this 4 lines of scripting?

Comment: Could anyone help me with this one ? if i solved this one then i can work on my other scripts

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it...

```
$connection = new mysqli('database_name', 'user', 'password', 'table_name');

$email = 'emailAddressYouWantToLookUp';

$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND status = 'Alive';";

$results = $connection->query($sql);

$emailFoundInDatabase = '';

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $emailFoundInDatabase = $row['email'];
    };
};

echo $emailFoundInDatabase;
```

Comment: Thanks its in the right direction but not usefull yet, Could someone change my 4 rules of script to msqli support ? as possible less possible changes

Comment: @RicardoBolder I've modified my answer to include some of your code, but you should be able to figure out how to use it from there.

Comment: I cleared the error from the first rule of the script i saw something on google similair.

This was my script:

$sql_email_check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT email 
FROM  users  WHERE email='$email' AND status='Alive'");

And now this:

$sql_email_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM users  
            WHERE email='$email' AND status='Alive'"); 

i replaced: $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], with $con


$con i have already dentifyed in a other filte with the connection with db and included in this file


Is this right and will it work ?

Comment: i have eddited my first post because the reply looks really messy

Answer (score -1):

Close!

The solution was

replacing: $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], with $con,

I have $con in a other file that makes a connection with the database and included in this script.

Also got a weird error about

i replaced that with:

and now all error's are gone and this script is working 100%

Thanks